# Wordpress plugin development: Deliver other page to browser than requested in URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to write a wordpress plugin, which is able to deliver another page to the browser than requested in the URL. The plugin should not forward the browser to another URL (the browsers URL should not change).

Lets assume we have 2 wordpress pages: "page1" and "page2". The browser sends some post-data from a form to www.example.com/wordpress/page1. The plugin checks the post-data and decides to deliver page2 instead of page1.

Wordpress provides the global variable $pagename which stores the name of the page requested in the URL. Unfortunately wordpress doesn't care if you set $pagename to another value (as shown in my code). It still delivers page1 instead of page2...

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: example plugin
Description: This is just an example.
*/

function msu_wp_loaded() {
  global $pagename;

  if($pagename == "page1" && some_other_condition ) {
    $pagename = "page2";
  }

}
add_action('wp_loaded','msu_wp_loaded');

?>
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Are the pages using the same template?

Comment: Yes, they do...

Comment: Just trying to understand, you don't want the URL to change, you want to pull data from page 2 and show it on the current page? ....?

Comment: I want to show page2 instead of page1. The user should not see anything of page1.

Comment: If there is a solution to insert content from another page, i could create three pages: page1 will have no content, page2 and page3 will have some content. Then i could insert page2 or page3 depending on a condition into page1 if page1 is requested... This would also help.

Comment: You should redirect to page 2 instead of trying to render another content than the URL should deliver

Comment: That would cause another http request by the browser. I want to avoid this because this will cause the whole data processing to be done again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create two different pages, each one with the different content. Then, I would use pre_get_posts to get a *postid* parameter. This way, you won't have to deal with redirections.

```
function conditional_change_content_by_id( $query ){
    if( $query->is_page( YOURPAGEID ) && $query->is_main_query() && (isset($_POST["pageid"]) && !empty($_POST["pageid"])) ) {
        $query->set( 'page_id', $_POST["pageid"] );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'conditional_change_content_by_id' );
```